# Pass nothing (not null) to the server if the argument is None

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, anorm

I have a model:

```
case class MyModel(
  id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned,
  startsAt: Option[DateTime] = None,
  addedAt: Option[DateTime] = None
) 

object MyModel {

// .....................
SQL("""
    INSERT INTO my_table(starts_at)
    VALUES ({startsAt})
    """
    ).on('startsAt -> newItem.startsAt).executeInsert()

}
```

Both `startst_at` and `added_at` have a default value of `now()` in Postgresql and don't allow null values in them. It doesn't cause any error for `addedAt` (because I never pass it to the server from the client) but it does cause the error for `startsAt` if it's not specified at `newItem.startsAt` and, thus, is equal to `None` and, thus, it's being passed as `null`.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "starts_at" violates not-null constraint
```

What I want is be able to specify `startsAt` whenever I want it and pass it to the server, meaning if I specify it then that value should be passed to the server, if not - **nothing** should be passed and the server should use its default value now(). I don't want  to specify the default value at the client because it's already set at the server at the db level.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the only solution is like `startsAt match { case Some(s) => "insert with {s}" case None => "insert without {s}" }`. `Anorm` is a simple JDBC wrapper. I doubt you can tweak it not to send null fields

Comment: @serejja, yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this SQL fix:

```
insert into my_table(starts_at)
values (COALESCE({startsAt}, now())
```

**Updated: requirement is to use the default value of the column**

The only way that I know of to get the server to use the default value of a column in an insert, is not to mention that column in the columns list. For example (not tested):

```
startsAt.map { date =>
  SQL("""insert into my_table(starts_at) values({startsAt})""")
    .on('startsAt -> date)
    .execute()
}.orElse {
  SQL("""insert into my_table() values()""")
    .execute()
}
```

Comment: It's `coalesce({startsAt}, now())` for postgres

Comment: I said, the value "now()" is already specified at the server. Your solution is using now() also at the client. I can use newItem.startsAt.getOrElse(DateTime.now()) instead because it's simpler. But I don't want this.

Comment: the now() in SQL would be executed on the server, not at the client.

Comment: I suppose Alex means he doesn't want to duplicate `now()` in schema and client code. This would cause complications if default value changes

Comment: `the value "now()" is already specified at the server (in the table definition) as the default value for the column starts_at`

Comment: @Alex, in my solution, `now()` is absolutely going to be evaluated at the server. That is what you want, isn't it?

Comment: OK, just read the rest of the comments. In case of `null`, you would like to use the default value, whatever it is. At the moment it happens to be `now()`. The way to achieve that is to use a different SQL insert when `starts_at` is `None`, which omits `starts_at` from the `values` list. Sadly, not so neat.

Comment: @ Alex @serejja ok. fair enough!